# Nginx configuration for jenkins port

Tags: ssl, nginx, jenkins

I'm new to Nginx and I have the following problem in the configuration: since I've set up the ssl certificate I can no longer access the Jenkins admin (which I did by accessing mydomanin.net:8080). 
Here is the configuration I have now set in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default :

```
server {
         listen 80 default_server;
         listen [::]:80 default_server;
         server_name mydomain.net;
         return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; 
       }

server {
        server_name mydomain.net;

        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-mydomain.net.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/foldername;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                     error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
                   }
       }
```

Everything works fine but I have to be able to access the Jenkins admin on port 8080. If I try it now I get a *This site can’t provide a secure connection ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*.

I have tried setting up another server block with listen on port 8080 but with no success. Also, I've tried to add another listen on the existing server block, same outcome :(.

Any tips that would set me on the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does your new ssl site enforce *HTTP Strict Transport Security*? In which case your browser is trying to use `https` on port 8080.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes, that's what's happening. Is there any way to edit the nginx config so I can reach the 8080 port  (which is the Jenkins admin) with the set up I currently have in place?

Comment: If you keep your existing HSTS policy, you will need to use a different browser, use a different server name, or perhaps connect using the IP address.

Comment: @RichardSmith ok but how do I configure that in my nginx config ?

Comment: You could try a reverse proxy from your ssl site, [something like this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx) perhaps.